# How to store secret strings on a GEM?

Tags: ruby, security, rubygems

I wrote a ruby gem to interact with a webservice. The gem contains the hardcoded value of `client id` and `application secret`.

So anyone else can use my data on his script and I will be charged for his requests. :(

On other hands it would be bad for the users if they have to create a new app in order to get a new personal `application secret`.

Any idea on how to store these info in a secure way?

Answer (score 0):

While it might be OK to hardcode values in internal-only, early stage prototypes or temporary solution it is usually not advisable to hardcode values that normally change from application to application and most certainly not password or security tokens!

I would recommend that you made these values configurable in ways that people can easily set them via standard environment variables (very common in PaaS environments such as Heroku) or via initializers if need be. Exceptions are sane default values such as development database URLs (ex: redis' default `127.0.0.1:6379`)

**Example**

```
module MyGem
  class Configuration
    attr_writer :client_id, :application_secret, :url

    # Expects a MY_GEM_CLIENT_ID env var to be set in production
    def client_id
      @client_id ||= ENV.fetch('MY_GEM_CLIENT_ID', 'CLIENT_ID')
    end

    # Expects a MY_GEM_APPLICATION_SECRET env var to be set in production    
    def application_secret
      @application_secret ||= ENV.fetch('MY_GEM_APPLICATION_SECRET', 'SECRET')
    end

    # ENV driven config but with working default
    def url
      @url ||= ENV.fetch('MY_GEM_URL', 'https://myservice.com/v1/api')
    end
  end

  def self.configure(&block)
    block.call(configuration)
  end

  def self.configuration
    @configuration ||= Configuration.new
  end
end
```

**Initializer-based config of the code above**

```
# config/initializers/my_gem.rb in Rails
# CustomConfigObject could be a Mixlib configuration object
MyGem.configure do |config|
  config.client_id = CustomConfigObject.my_gem.client_id
  config.application_sercret = CustomConfigObject.my_gem.application_secret
  config.url = CustomConfigObject.my_gem.url
end
```

If you **absolutely** need to provide a default "sandbox" set of Client ID and Application Secret you can provide those values as defaults in the code above (the second argument to `ENV.fetch()`), but I'd recommend either adding a `sandbox` boolean setting that can be set to true/false and sent with API calls, at which point your API would process those as sandbox / dev calls or, preferably, add support for account-specific sandbox credentials.

Comment: The issue with a default hard coded app_secret is that the user can read it and use for his app. If I can make another example let's think about a Google API key. The key should be kept secret or a user can abuse of it (and you will be charged for all his requests).  With a compiled app usually the key is hard coded and obfuscated inside the binary but ruby is not compiled...

Comment: That's why I mentioned in my answer that you should never include those in your gem :) Even in compiled apps its relatively easy to extract keys by inspecting memory (that's how most software is cracked). If your gem relies on a Google API key being available, then its the user's responsibilities to provide one - not the gem's creators. Is that the case with your gem?

Comment: Yes this is the case. If you make a gem for other devs I agree with you, but if you make a tool for the final user you should provide your own API key. I would say that this is a general question: "can I store private data in a ruby script?"

Comment: Ah, so your gem is not meant for the general public but it is, rather, more of a script to be used by trusted users in a trusted environment?

Comment: The script was intended for the final user non-developer. But at this point I give up, there is no real way to store *my* private information on a script that is distributed. So if the use  want to use my script, he need to register on the website and obtain his own API key.

Comment: I agree with you. Unless this was a trusted environment (like your own company) distributing credentials is no-no.